# Is there any way to setup multiple UIwebviews with one controller in Xcode?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, viewcontroller

I am working on a PDF viewer and I want to be able to point a TableView Controller to one controller, and one UIwebview to avoid having a massive number of both. Is this possible?

Whats the easiest way to go about doing this ( I am a newbie)?

Comment: You have a table view controller, and if you tap on a cell, you want a new view controller to appear? And that view controller shows the UIWebView?

Comment: I don't think you want more than one web view. I think when you tap on a cell you would bring up the same web view, but it would point to a different url.

Comment: Yes thats Correct beeef. And yes, @Jacob I would want the same UIwebview. I did get it figured out with the help of someone else. How would you reference a different URL?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want more than one web view. I think when you tap on a cell you would bring up the same web view, but it would point to a different url. You would just change the url it points to before you display the web view again:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"]]];
```